# How to implement an array with VBA Excel?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, for-loop

I have this code here, and I want to add an array with [12] (the 12 months).

The lines with `//` are the ones that I need to implement but I don't understand well how to do it!

The rest works fine :)

```
Sub titleHere()
Dim i As Long, var As Long
var = 0
//ARRAY[12] arr = {"Jan", "Fev", "Mar", etc...}

//Sheets("arr[0]").Cells(4, 3).Value = Sheets("INTRO").Cells(5, 2).Value
//For m = 1 To 11
    For i = 3 To 32
        If Cells(i, 19).Value = "C" Or Cells(i, 19).Value = "c" Then
            If Cells(i, 20) = 0 Then
                var = Sheets("INTRO").Cells(2, 2).Value
            Else
                var = Sheets("INTRO").Cells(2, 2).Value - Cells(i, 20).Value
          End If
        Else
            var = 0
        End If
//        Sheets("arr[m]").Cells(4, 3) = Sheets("arr[m]").Cells(4, 3) - var
        Next
//    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: `arr = Array("Jan", "Fev", "Mar")` then use `Sheets(arr(0))` and so on.

Comment: Once you've done what @Rory suggested, change the sheet statement outside the `FOR` loop to: `Sheets(arr(0)).Cells(4, 3).Value = Sheets("INTRO").Cells(5, 2).Value`. Change the `FOR` statement to: `For m = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)`. Then change sheet statement inside the `FOR` loop to: `Sheets(arr(m)).Cells(4, 3) = Sheets(arr(m)).Cells(4, 3) - var`

Comment: If `INTRO` is one worksheet, `Worksheets(arr(m))` is another (`Jan` to `Dec`), where is `Cells(i, 19)` located, in a third worksheet? In which worksheet is the code located?

Comment: Yes INTRO and Jan, Fev, Mars... are all worksheets! The objective is to take a value in INTRO and change it in every worksheet :)

Answer (score 1):

### Loop Worksheets by Month

- Not sure if I understood everything correctly, but with a few tweaks it should help you to get the job done.
- Off course, change the months to the months in your language.

**A Quick Fix**

```
Option Explicit

Sub titleHere()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' The workbook containing this code.
    
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Set ws1 = wb.Worksheets("INTRO")
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Set ws2 = wb.ActiveSheet ' ?
    
    Dim arr As Variant
    arr = Array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", _
                "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec")
    
    Dim m As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim var As Long
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets(arr(LBound(arr)))
    ws.Cells(4, 3).Value = ws1.Cells(5, 2).Value
    
    For m = LBound(arr) + 1 To UBound(arr)
        Set ws = wb.Worksheets(arr(m))
        For i = 3 To 32
            If StrComp(ws2.Cells(i, 19).Value, "c", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                If ws2.Cells(i, 20) = 0 Then
                    var = ws1.Cells(2, 2).Value
                Else
                    var = ws1.Cells(2, 2).Value - ws2.Cells(i, 20).Value
                End If
            Else
                var = 0
            End If
                ws.Cells(4, 3) = ws.Cells(4, 3) - var
        Next i
    Next m

End Sub
```

Comment: Why do you use Worksheet and Workbook? I dont understand the utility if we use Sheets("") ?

Comment: Sheets is a collection of worksheets, charts ... If the code is about worksheets, then I like to use `Worksheets`. You cannot have cells and ranges in a chart. The workbook is an object that contains worksheets (sheets), so if you use the exact workbook and exact worksheet (aka if you qualify it or create a reference to it), then there is a slim chance of error. You will encounter those errors soon enough.

Comment: Ok I understand!! I'm gonna try it :D By the way, I need to do one thing only during the first [12] for loop. I tried this but I says error:
`If m = arr(0) Then .... Else .... Enf If` I tried with `m = 0` too and it doesn't work too!

Comment: OH! It says `out of range` clearly because of the `arr(m-1)` I only want to use m-1 when I do my first for loop. `        If m = arr(0) Then
        Sheets(arr(m)).Cells(4, 3) = Sheets(arr(m)).Cells(4, 3) - var
        Else
            Sheets(arr(m)).Cells(4, 3) = Sheets(arr(m - 1)).Cells(4, 3) - var
        End If`

Comment: `m` will never be `Arr(0)` because `m` is a number and Arr(0) is "Jan".

Comment: Hey! Can you please see it and help me with some errors :O 
https://codeshare.io/5N8W91

Comment: Hi Pe Dro, I assume this is the follow on from Yesterdays code? Small issue in what you shared: `Sheets("arr(1)")` You don't need double quotes as it's a variable resulting in a string so make it `Sheets(arr(1))`. There is another spot in the same line where you need to remove the double quotes also. Also when commenting in VBA use a single quote `'` instead of `////` This way if anyone copies and pastes your code into the editor it will compile with the comments rather than erroring.

Comment: also put `, arr as variant` on the end of your DIM line, best to dimension everything. Also add `m as long`

Comment: Thanks again!! It doesn't work but I have no errors now!! I'll try to figure out where's the problem hahahah

Comment: I got it!! <3 <3

Comment: Good stuff, glad you got it sorted. Maybe update your question and post your final code at the bottom so people can learn from it if they have similar problems.